# Select from multiple tables by id, and sort on other column

Tags: mysql

I would like to execute a query but I can't get the desired result.

I have two tables (**A & B**) with the same columns `tag_id` and `priority`.

The two tables also have some other columns (`image` & `text`). I would like to select all the rows where the `tag_id` equals a given variable and I want to sort the result on `priority`.

(the column `priority` is unique for every row)

[image: Db drawing]

What kind of query should I use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show you efforts first

Comment: i tried to 'inner join' on the tag_id, and then group the 'priority' and order it ascending. that didnt work.

Comment: is TAG_ID a nullable value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddeling around for a while i found a solution.

```
SELECT priority, text, null AS image 
FROM A
WHERE tag_id = x
UNION ALL 
SELECT priority, null, image
FROM B
WHERE tag_id = x
ORDER BY priority
```

This way the fields that the **other** table doesnt have, get set to null.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM A, B 
WHERE A.tag_id = B.tag_id 
    AND A.tag_id = "somevalue" 
ORDER BY A.priority ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it I suppose:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.tag_id = B.tag_id and A.tag_id = $YourVariable ORDER BY A.priority, B.priority
```

Comment: It always returns no rows, (num_rows() returns false). I also think you mean `ORDER BY` instead of `SORT BY`.

Comment: If tag_id has the same occurences in A as in B, and you set $yourvariable to one of these values, it should return at least one row. You were right about the ORDER BY, my mistake, changed it, thanks :-)

Comment: Your solution doesnt give the result i wanted, Both tables also have the same field **priority** but the values are unique for each row. I actually found a solution but i wonder if there's a more elegant way of doing it. [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960353/select-from-multiple-tables-by-id-and-sort-on-other-collum/28971444#28971444) (i can accept it as answer tomorrow)

Comment: Depending on how you want the data exactly, it could also be done like this: SELECT A.priority AS a_prio, B.priority AS b_prio, A.text, B.image
FROM A, B
WHERE A.tag_id = B.tag_id
AND A.tag_id =2
ORDER BY A.priority, B.priority                                    But if that's not what you want, then I think your solution is the only possible one.

Comment: I think the ORDER BY orders the two fields separately, But i need them combined and order it in one go, thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. The most important issue for you is that the rows from both tables are in one set, ordered by overal priority, not priority per table. Ok, then yours is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
select *
from a
join b on b.tag_id = a.tag_id
where a.tag_id = x
order by a.priority asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT A.TAG_ID, A.PRIORITY, A.TEXT, B.IMAGE
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.TAG_ID = B.TAG_ID
WHERE A.TAG_ID = @TAG_ID
ORDER BY A.PRIORITY
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select tag_id, priority
  from A
 where tag_id = <your search value>
 union all
select tag_id, priority
  from B
 where tag_id = <your search value>
order by 2
```